Problem with JQ selecting specific keys based on selecting
I have a problem with JQ where I can't get the correct fields. I have don't so many tutorials but can't seem to get this. I am trying to get only the "cpu" for the "mysql" container, but I keep getting both "sidecar, and mysql". Honestly I think it is my misunderstanding of JQ so please feel free to point out what I am misunderstanding.
I keep getting the following but should ONLY see "2100m":
null
2100m

jq -r --arg _NAME "mysql-innodb-cluster-0" #Only get the container with this specific name
'.items[]                                  #Work on all items
| select(.metadata.name == $_NAME )        #Work on the container that has this name
| .spec.containers                         #Get the specific key, which will be an object here.
select(.[].name=="sidecar" | not )       #Now that you have the Container Array only use the one that IS NOT named "sidecar"
| .[].resources.limits.cpu '               #you now have the MySQL container get ONLY it's "cpu" value.
Command I use:
jq -r --arg _NAME "mysql-innodb-cluster-0" '.items[] | select(.metadata.name == $_NAME ) | .spec.containers | select(.[].name=="sidecar" | not ) | .[].resources.limits.cpu ' --raw-output /tmp/test.json


test.json
{
 "apiVersion": "v1",
"items": [
{
  "apiVersion": "v1",
  "kind": "Pod",
  "metadata": {
    "name": "mysql-innodb-cluster-0"
  },
  "spec": {
    "containers": [
      {
        "name": "sidecar",
        "resources": {}
      },
      {
        "name": "mysql",
        "resources": {
          "limits": {
            "cpu": "2100m",
            "memory": "5G"
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
 ],
"kind": "List"
}


After you selected the correct name, you'll need to continue select'ing on the .spec.containers to find the one with name === "mysql" and then select the .resources.limits.cpu from that object:
.items[] | select(.metadata.name == $_NAME) | (.spec.containers[] | select(.name == "mysql").resources?.limits?.cpu)

Will output:
"2100m"


Online JqPlay Demo

it works! Can I ask you why the question marks on resources and limits? I am guessing it's for an "if exists" I haven't seen this format.

Please check there documentation about ?. It's a way of not erroring should resources (or the others) not exist on the object. I've added it just to be sure.
